# Javascript: selecting values from a dropdown

Tags: javascript

I had a standard calculation javascript and now I need to add-in multiple calculations based on a user-selected value - can't seem to get it to work....!  Any chance someone could have a look and tell me where I'm going wrong???

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculate() {
  var noPeople = document.ContactForm.noPeople.value;
  var ddl = document.getElementById("menuType");
  var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
  var noPeople_excess = (noPeople-6);

  if (selectedValue == 3)  {
    var basic = 337;
    var marchCost = (50*noPeople);
    if (marchCost <= basic)         {
      document.ContactForm.marchCost.value = 337;
      document.ContactForm.marchCostVin.value = basic +(noPeople*25)
    } else {
      document.ContactForm.marchCost.value = basic +(noPeople_excess*34);
      document.ContactForm.marchCostVin.value = basic +(noPeople_excess*34)+(noPeople*25)
    }
  } else (selectedValue == 4)  {
    var basic = 368;
    var marchCost = (55*noPeople);
    if (marchCost <= basic) {
      document.ContactForm.marchCost.value = 368;
      document.ContactForm.marchCostVin.value = basic +(noPeople*25)
    } else {
      document.ContactForm.marchCost.value = basic +(noPeople_excess*44);
      document.ContactForm.marchCostVin.value = basic +(noPeople_excess*44)+(noPeople*25)
    }
  } else (selectedValue == 5) {
    var basic = 419;
    var marchCost = (60*noPeople);
    if (marchCost <= basic) {
      document.ContactForm.marchCost.value = 419;
      document.ContactForm.marchCostVin.value = basic +(noPeople*25)
    } else {
      document.ContactForm.marchCost.value = basic +(noPeople_excess*54);
      document.ContactForm.marchCostVin.value = basic +(noPeople_excess*54)+(noPeople*25)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what's exactly is wrong?

Comment: Are you expecting us to debug this entire thing? Isolate only the problematic part and post it

Comment: Basically, when there was no dropdown, the calculation worked and cost was given on the form.  Now that there are multiple values to choose from, nothing happens, nothing appears on the form.

Comment: your elses are missing an if.. suggest switch(selectedvalue) { case 3: ... etc would be easier to read..

Comment: Basically, there are 3 options to choose from; if option 1 is chosen, then perform the appropriate calculation....?

Comment: If you have an answer, then [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the question, don't edit the question to integrate the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This question was indeed many times answered, however here is a simple solution for you:

```
    //get select value and assing to an input element
function setValue(selectId, elemId) {
    var thisID = selectId, 
    valueSelected = document.getElementById(thisID).value
    console.log(thisID + ' has value of ' + valueSelected);
    document.getElementById(elemId).value = valueSelected;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/rnenKVaNcJ9RhqLzUaWi

regards.

Answer (score 0):

I might be confused about the two DDLs, but either the selected value should be the selectedIndex to compare with integers:

```
var selectedValue = ddl.selectedIndex;
```

or the conditions should be checking strings:

```
if (selectedValue == "3"){
```

Answer (score 0):

your elses are missing an if.. eg: else if (selectedvalue==4)

I suggest using switch(selectedvalue) { case 3: ... break; case 4: ...etc 
would be easier to read in this case, especially if you add more options.

Comment: Yeah, you're right - there was one "else if" missing....! put it in and all's working ok.  Thanks.